# Proper way to change DisplayName of Email in MVCMailer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, mvcmailer

I looking to change the display name in a Email using MVCMailer.  Instead of the client seeing  From: custmerservice@xyzCompany.com they will see "xyzCompany Customer Service".
I have looked all around the internet and can not find any documentation that explains how.

USERMAILER.CS

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Welcome(string sentTo, string replyTo)
        {

            return Populate(x =>
            {
                x.Subject = "Welcome";
                x.ViewName = "Welcome"; //View name of email going out.
                x.ReplyToList.Clear();
                x.ReplyToList.Add(replyTo);
                x.To.Add(sentTo);
                x.From.DisplayName("xyz Company Customer Service"); 
                x.From = new MailAddress("customerservice@xyzCompany.com");
                x.ViewName = "WelcomeEmail"; //View name of email going out.
            });
         }
```

The line 'x.From.DisplayName("xyz Company Customer Service")' gives me an error: system.net.mail.mailaddress.DisplayName can not be used as a method.

Can anyone please tell me how to properly change the displayname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DisplayName` is a property of the [`MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress_properties.aspx) class. You can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx) of the constructor to specify it:

```
x.From = new MailAddress(address: "customerservice@xyzCompany.com", displayName: "xyz Company Customer Service");
```

**Update based on comment:**

The `DisplayName` property has no (or a private) setter, meaning you can only set it through the constructor of `MailAddress`, but not through the property itself.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It worked!  However, the second option: x.From.DisplayName = "xyz Company Customer Service";  does not work for me. It is now giving me an error saying it's readonly.

Comment: @user2789697 you're welcome. This means that `DisplayName` is read-only, I updated my answer.

Comment: @user2789697 also, please mark this as the answer for people with the same question.